# Matrix Multiplication MPI + OMP

Tags: matrix, mpi, multiplication, openmp

I'm having a problem with my code for matrix multiplication using both MPI and OMP. Code is correctly compiled but it give me wrong result,values in matrix c(in matmul function) are to big and matrix C(in main) doesn't even get results from function matmul. If anyone knows how to fix it,please help.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int offset,rows,br_elemenata,cvor_id,cvor,ukupno;
MPI_Status status;

double gettime(void) {
   struct timeval tv;
   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
   return tv.tv_sec + 1e-6 * tv.tv_usec;
}

void matfill(long N, double *mat, double val) {
   long i, j;

   for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
      for(j = 0; j < N; j ++)
         mat[i * N + j] = val;
}

void matmul(long N, double *a, double *b, double *c) {
   long i, j, k;

  br_elemenata = N / ukupno;            //odredjujemo broj elemenata po cvoru

  if (N % ukupno != 0) br_elemenata++;      //inkrementujemo broj elemenata po cvoru kako ne bismo neki izostavili

  if (cvor == 0){
    for (cvor_id=1;cvor_id<ukupno;cvor_id++){
      offset = cvor_id * br_elemenata;
      rows = N - offset;
      if (rows > br_elemenata)
    rows = br_elemenata;
      // slanje podataka sa cvora 0 na ostale cvorove
      MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, cvor_id, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, cvor_id, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(a+offset, rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, cvor_id, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(b, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, cvor_id, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  offset = 0;
  rows = br_elemenata;
  } else {
    // Primanje podataka sa cvora 0
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(a+offset, rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(b, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

#pragma omp parallel for shared(a,b,c) private(i,j,k)
   for (i = offset; i < offset + rows; i ++)
      for (j = 0; j < N; j ++)
         for (k = 0; k < N; k ++)
            c[i + j] += a[i + k] * b[k * N + j];
  printf("Clan: %5.2f\n",c[i]);
  if (cvor == 0) {
    for (cvor_id = 1; cvor_id < ukupno; cvor_id++) {
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, cvor_id, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, cvor_id, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(c+offset, rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, cvor_id, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
  } else {
    MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(c+offset, rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   long N;
   double *A, *B, *C, t;


   MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);       //Inicijalizacija MPI

   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&ukupno);   //odredjujemo ukupan broj cvorova
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&cvor);     //odredjuje redni broj cvora, nacin da se svaki cvor identifikuje u komunikaciji


   if (argc!=2) {
     if (cvor==0) printf("Morate unijeti dimenziju matrice!");
     MPI_Finalize();                        // ako ne postoji argument pri pozivu funkcije, zavrsiti program
     return 1;
   }

   N = atoi(argv[1]);
   A = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
   B = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
   C = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
   matfill(N, A, 1.0);
   matfill(N, B, 2.0);
   matfill(N, C, 0.0);




   t = gettime();
   matmul(N, A, B, C);
   t = gettime() - t;

   // if (cvor == 0){
      fprintf(stdout, "%ld\t%le\t%le\n", N, t, (2 * N - 1) * N * N / t);
      fflush(stdout);

      printf("Clan: %f\n",C[6]);
  //  }

   free(A);
   free(B);
   free(C);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is the `offset` during communication operations. It should be `offset*N`.

Corrected code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int offset,rows,br_elemenata,cvor_id,cvor,ukupno;
MPI_Status status;

double gettime(void) {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec + 1e-6 * tv.tv_usec;
}

void matfill(long N, double *mat, double val) {
    long i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
        for(j = 0; j < N; j ++)
            mat[i * N + j] = val;
}

void matprint(long N, double *mat) {
    long i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i ++){
        for(j = 0; j < N; j ++){
            printf("%g ",mat[i*N+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void matdiag(long N, double *mat, double val) {
    long i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
        for(j = 0; j < N; j ++)
            if(i==j){
                mat[i * N + j] = (double)i;
            }else{
                mat[i * N + j] =0;
            }
}

void matmul(long N, double *a, double *b, double *c) {
    long i, j, k;

    br_elemenata = N / ukupno;            //odredjujemo broj elemenata po cvoru

    if (N % ukupno != 0) br_elemenata++;      //inkrementujemo broj elemenata po cvoru kako ne bismo neki izostavili

    if (cvor == 0){
        for (cvor_id=1;cvor_id<ukupno;cvor_id++){
            offset = cvor_id * br_elemenata;
            rows = N - offset;
            if (rows > br_elemenata)
                rows = br_elemenata;
            // slanje podataka sa cvora 0 na ostale cvorove
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, cvor_id, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, cvor_id, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(a+(offset*N), rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, cvor_id, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(b, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, cvor_id, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        offset = 0;
        rows = br_elemenata;
    } else {
        // Primanje podataka sa cvora 0
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(a+(offset*N), rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(b, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

#pragma omp parallel for shared(a,b,c) private(i,j,k)
    for (i = offset; i < offset + rows; i ++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j ++)
            for (k = 0; k < N; k ++)
                c[i*N + j] += a[i*N + k] * b[k * N + j];
    printf("Clan: %5.2f\n",c[i]);
    if (cvor == 0) {
        for (cvor_id = 1; cvor_id < ukupno; cvor_id++) {
            MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, cvor_id, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, cvor_id, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(c+(N*offset), rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, cvor_id, 6, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }
    } else {
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(c+(N*offset), rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 6, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long N;
    double *A, *B, *C, t;


    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);       //Inicijalizacija MPI

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&ukupno);   //odredjujemo ukupan broj cvorova
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&cvor);     //odredjuje redni broj cvora, nacin da se svaki cvor identifikuje u komunikaciji


    if (argc!=2) {
        if (cvor==0) printf("Morate unijeti dimenziju matrice!");
        MPI_Finalize();                        // ako ne postoji argument pri pozivu funkcije, zavrsiti program
        return 1;
    }

    N = atoi(argv[1]);
    A = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
    B = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
    C = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
    matfill(N, A, 1.0);
    matfill(N, B, 2.0);
    matfill(N, C, 0.0);
    matdiag(N,A, 1) ;




    t = gettime();
    matmul(N, A, B, C);
    t = gettime() - t;

    if (cvor == 0){
        fprintf(stdout, "%ld\t%le\t%le\n", N, t, (2 * N - 1) * N * N / t);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("Clan: %f\n",C[6]);
        printf("A\n");
        matprint(N, A) ;
        printf("B\n");
        matprint(N, B) ;
        printf("C\n");
        matprint(N, C) ;

    }


    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To compile : `mpicc main.c -o main` To run : `mpirun -np 4 main`

If you wish to go further, you will be interested by the [`MPI_Bcast()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Bcast.html) function, which sends the same thing to everyone. [`MPI_Scatter()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Scatter.html) and [`MPI_Gather()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Gather.html) are helpful to distribute matrices or get it back on a given process.

Moreover,  the [`dgemm()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f.html) function of [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f.html) may be used to speed up the computation on a given process.

To reduce the memory footprint, the allocated size of `A` and `C` may be decreased to account for `br_elemenata` (except on process 0)...and offsets will have to change...again !